# Processid (PID) reuse problem with xCode

Tags: php, xcode, debugging, profiling, php-5.3

I have a large custom CMS and I use xcode to run a profiler to get debug information. So, I perform different functions in my CMS and "HOPE" to get ALL information via xDebug.

Lets say I perform two functions:

```
1. Load a listing of users 
2. Deleted a user 
   2.1 Calls an AJAX script to delete user.
```

Now, due to the process id reuse, there is a chance (happens to me 8 of 10 times) that instead of 3 cache files I have 2, one of the processId is reused. BUMMER

Can this problem be overcomed ? How would it work..

..jacking up Keep-Alive isn't a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%p.%u` instead of the standard  `xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%p` would append a micro-second suffix. See [this link](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#trace_output_name) for more naming options, having a script name for instance can make your life even easier.